# Oja's rule gives unit eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Does Oja's rule for normalized Hebbian learning always result in a unit eigenvector which corresponds to the largest eigenvalue? Or are there any specific conditions or assumptions under which this is true? Does Oja's rule require explicit normalization of the unit vector, and what would be the effect of doing so, if any?

Edit for explaining [Oja's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oja%27s_rule)

Given a set of $M$ points $x$ in $n$ dimensions, Oja's rule is an iterative update rule that allows to find a direction $w$ that is equivalent to finding the maximal eigenvector (or first principal component) using the following update rule (here $\eta$ is the learning rate, a parameter) for few iterations

$\Delta w = \eta V_i (x_i - V_i w)$, where $V_i=\langle w, x_i\rangle$, $\forall i=\{1,...,M\}$

The second term is essentially meant to be a ''forgetting factor'' in order to ensure that the vector $w$ does not grow unbounded, which may cause the update rule to not converge. What conditions are required for this rule to necessarily converge?

Comment: You would get more responses if you explained what Oja's rule is (mathematically, not in terms of learning problems).

Comment: Which matrix are you hoping to find the eigenvectors of? What do you do with that $\Delta w$ (which depends on $i$, by the way) once you have computed it?

Comment: I create a dataset of 20 samples in 2 dimensions initialized with random values as `data=[rand{10,2)+14;rand(10,2)-14];`. Here the samples are displaced by 14 units. I iterate over this dataset sample by sample and compute $\Delta w$ and update the weight vector $w=w_{old}+\Delta w$. This is repeated for a few iterations over the dataset. I find that after a few iterations $w \rightarrow \infty$